# Do I need to add a ground conductor when replacing a wall light fixture?

Tags: basement

I have a new wall light that has 2 wires negative and positive but no ground the fixture screws directly to the wall and mot into a box do i need to add a ground wire to the fixture

Comment: Where are you on this planet? How in the world do you have a light fixture that lacks a box?  What make and model is this *thing* anyway?

Comment: FYI, there are no "positive" or "negative" in AC wiring. You have a hot and a neutral.

Comment: This fixture does not have a box you obviously dont know what you are talking about maybe return to dummy land

Answer (score 1):

If the fixture has the 'class II' (double-insulaton) logo on:
[image: Class II logo],
 you don't need to add a ground, also if the circuit is GFCI protected you don't need a ground, if light is 'out of reach' lack of ground may not be a problem (as long as you turn the breaker off when changhing a bulb).

In general, if all the fixture casing is made of insulating materials, ground is not required.